# Not able to overwrite predefined h1 values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have given the desired values to h1 tag in my styles.css file, but the predefined values are not getting overwritten.

```css
media (min-width: 1200px) .h1,
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.h1,
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.375rem + 1.5vw);
}

.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<h3>Hello world</h3>
<h4>Hello world</h4>
<h5>Hello world</h5>
<h6>Hello world</h6>

<hr>

<div class="h1">Hello world</div>
<div class="h2">Hello world</div>
<div class="h3">Hello world</div>
<div class="h4">Hello world</div>
<div class="h5">Hello world</div>
<div class="h6">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: Please may you add some code to the question? Preferably as a [mcve]. Please do not post it as images.

Comment: No, sorry. Please may you remove the comment and edit the question?

Comment: `media (min-width: 1200px) .h1 ... ` already shows 2 issues. Mediaqueries need an @media and a brace to open ->`@media (min-width: 1200px) { .h1 ...`

Comment: I added some HTML to hopefully better show the issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include exactly what you are expecting that isn't happening or what is happening that you are not expecting.

Comment: People take heed to close a question or downvote it or its answers.
We should atleast wait to let the OP add additional details when someone comments about that, or let the OP at least try the answers.

Comment: @MShoaibQureshi its simply because most questions here hold no value. They not meeting the guidelines, are duplicates or could be self-anwsered with little to no research-efford. The sites intention are to provide high-quality informations and not just tons of low-value posts. This site is not a forum nor a tutorial! If the OP would edit the question and provide the informations asked for, we would re-open the question. Until then I highly recommend to read and obey the guidelines (they exist for a reason).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might need to use reset css.
And mainly place your custom css file after all style files in the header.

Comment: We can't know if a reset would help here as the OP has given next to no information

Comment: despite of that this should have been given then as comment not as an anwser

Comment: This is a valid answer. let the OP try atleast please or else I can give other information or add additional solution if this dosent work.
BUT most of the times it works this way, so it cannot be ruled out.

Comment: yes but it is a wild and vague guess. An anwser should always be a 100% definite solution of an issue. As we dont have any detailed information this is only a geuss and as such should be given as a comment not as an anwser.

Comment: Do you think this cannot be a solution of these kind of cases?

Comment: I think that it might can solve it but this will not solve with 100% certainty and like I said multiple times befor, as such doesnt not fulfill the criteria for an anwser

Comment: Why do we have here option of multiple answers if only one is accepted 100% solution?
If any other person answers something different that is actually accepted as answer, thats ok. And this means other not accepted answers are not solutions ?

Comment: because there better and worse solution. Most issues can be solved multiple ways. Where some anwser go for simplicity, some anwser might have a more understandable explanation of the issue and solution. For example if the question would be `how to center an element` I could at least tell you 20 different methods. All of them solving the issue with 100% certainty. Some methods would be out-dated or simply to complicated and as such woul be downvoted over more simple and clean solutions.

Comment: So you think the 2nd answer that actually starts with a request to clarify the question is correct?
Or does that get a down vote. Still the question is vague and that answers is also uncertain.

Comment: Thanks Shoib it worked

Comment: My answer should not have gotten downvotes as the OP had not even tried it, It was given downvotes with in a matter of 3-5 min.

The newbies get stuck most often on simple stuff and my answer has to possibility to resolve the issue. Atleast let it be tried

Comment: Welcome @AnkurKhattri, Thats great!,
Please upvote and accept this as the answer as it worked. It would be very kind of you.

Comment: I am trying to upvote it but it's not happening

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.., it would be your rank in the way., you can upvote later when your rank is increased...

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your terminology and intention. You asked for h1 *tag* (really, tag?), and in your code there are multiple style of both h1 *element* (`h1`) and  *class* (`.h1`).

As @tacoshy pointed out, first the media query needs to be fixed (`@media (min-width: 1200px) {...}`) and with brackets to specify the scope.

Currently, it reads at *starting at 1200px*, both your **h1** and **.h1** have `font-size: 2.5rem`. Below that breakpoint, your **h1** is `font-size: calc(1.375rem + 1.5vw);` and your **.h1** is `font-size: 3rem`.